# Proof verification: Prove that a tree with n vertices has n-1 edges

Tags: graph-theory, proof-verification, trees

This question is not a duplicate of the other questions of this time. I want to ask is how strong is the following proof that I am going to give from an examination point of view?

---

Proof:

Consider a tree $T$ with $n$ vertices. Let us reconstruct the tree from the root vertex.

When the first root vertex has been added, the number of edges is zero. After the root vertex, every vertex that is added to the construction of $T$ contributes one edge to $T$.

Adding the remaining $n-1$ vertices to the construction of $T$, after the root vertex, will add $n-1$ edges.

Therefore, after the reconstruction of $T$ is complete, $T$ will have $n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges.

Hence Proved.

---

Is this a sound proof at all?

Comment: I'm not happy with it

Comment: What is wrong with it?

Comment: What is your definition of a tree ?  There are many, so the one you're using is important.

Comment: @AninditKarmakar , your intuition is correct but your proof is not written in precise formal steps or algorithm.  `Adding the remaining n−1 vertices to the construction of T, after the root vertex, will add n−1 edges.` You need to tell your reader(or more precisely a dumb machine) how you are adding the n-1 edges.

Comment: I think Number945 is right in the sense that you are telling that you'll obtain a tree by iterative edge addition, but you didn't show the tree you obtain will be the tree in context. For whatever tree you'll obtain it will be true, but how can you say this about the tree we started with?

Answer (score 11):

Consider the tree with *n* vertices.
To Prove: The number of edges will be *n-1*.

Assume **P(n):** Number of edges  = *n-1* for the tree with *n* vertices.
*n* will be natural number.

**P(1):** For one node, there will be zero edges, since there is no other node to connect with.

**P(2):** For two nodes, Number of edges = *n-1* = *2-1* = *1*, since one edge is sufficient to connect two nodes in a tree.

...

Assume **P(n)** is true, i.e. for *n* number of vertices in a tree, number of edges = *n-1*.

Now, For **P(n+1)**,

the number of edges will be *(n-1)* + number of edges required to add *(n+1)th* node.

Every vertex that is added to the tree contributes one edge to the tree.

Thus, the number of edges required to add *(n+1)th* node = 1.

Thus the total number of edges will be *(n - 1) + 1* = *n -1+1* = *n* = *(n +1) - 1*.

Thus, **P(n+1)** is true.

So, Using Principle of Mathematical Induction, it is proved that for given n vertices, number of edges  = *n - 1*.

Comment: The statement "the number of edges will be $(n - 1)$ + number of edges required to add $(n + 1)$th node" is sweeping details under the rug. Consider a tree $T$ with $n + 1$ vertices. Pick any vertex, then delete that vertex and the $k \geq 1$ edges connecting it to $T$. Case 1 is that the resulting graph $T'$ on $n$ vertices is a tree (with $n - 1$ edges). Case 2 is that $T'$ is not a tree, so $T'$ must be disconnected (why?); this case is trickier to think about. It's best to delete not just any vertex, but a [leaf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1765836/).

Comment: P(n) must be: for "any" tree with n vertices. having that, for P(n+1) you must show that any tree with n+1 vertices is constructible from some tree with n vertices. this is easy to show using the change suggusted by @jskattt797.

Comment: The proof is incorrect/incomlete. What you are fundamentally saying is that if you have a tree with n vertex and n-1 edges, you can obtain a tree with n+1 vertices and n edges. You can add the new edge to any of the previous vertex, but how you didn't prove that doing this way you'll exhaust all the trees with n+1 vertices. What if there is a tree with n+1 vertices and not-n edges which is not covered under this construction?

Comment: @jskattt797 Couldn't you equivalently show that by adding a vertex, you are adding $k \geq 1$ edges, and then partition the possibilities into two cases: $k=1$ which completes the proof and $k > 1$ which creates a cycle and thus not a tree.

Comment: @NeelSandell What do you mean by "adding a vertex"? To a tree? That works if you assume that "every tree $T$ on $n + 1$ vertices is a tree on $n$ vertices with an additional vertex and $k$ edges to that vertex," which requires a separate proof. As you've noted, $k$ must be $1$, so the additional vertex is a leaf. Thus you can quickly prove the quoted proposition using the fact that $T$ has a leaf. I suggested using this fact in my first comment.

Comment: @jskattt797 In the inductive step, my goal is to show that if we have a tree with $n+1$ vertices, it also has $n$ edges. Take the tree from the inductive hypothesis ($n$ vertices and $n-1$ edges). This tree is a graph. If we add a vertex to a graph, we introduce $k \geq 0$ edges on the graph. $k=0$ disconnected. $k > 1$ cycle. $k=1$ tree. Isn't this a valid proof?

Comment: The inductive hypothesis is "if $T$ is a tree on $n$ vertices, then $T$ has $n - 1$ edges." So yes, under this assumption any tree (not sure what you mean by "the" tree) on $n$ vertices will have $n - 1$ edges. And yes, the only way to convert a tree on $n$ vertices into a tree on $n + 1$ vertices (without modifying the existing edges) is by adding a leaf. But how do you know that every tree on $n + 1$ vertices arises from this procedure? This is why you must prove the quoted proposition from my last comment.

Answer (score 4):

What seems missing from the proof is:

- After the $n$-th vertex is added, how do we know there exists some "unused" vertex  $v$ which is adjacent to a "used" vertex?
- How do we know that $v$ is not adjacent to multiple "used" vertices?
- How do we know that this algorithm will terminate, having used all the vertices?

Also note that not all trees are rooted (i.e., have a root vertex), but we can distinguish an arbitrary vertex to make it rooted.