# Eulerian formula proof by induction on edges question

Tags: inequality, graph-theory, connectedness, planar-graphs, graph-connectivity

Proof: Let $f, e, v$ denote the number of faces, edges, and vertices, respectively,
in a planar graph. Use induction on $e$ to prove that $f = e−v + 2$ (this
is known as Euler’s formula).

I think few similar questions were asked about this but I haven't seen one with induction on edges.
I also have a different approach which I am curious if it is correct or not. There are two questions I have in mind

1: Do we use normal induction or strong induction ? 
2: What kind of edge am I suppose to remove in the inductive step ? 
My approach:
Let us assume a graph $G=(V,E)$ such that $|E(G)| = e, |V(G)| = v, |F(G)| = f$ 
Base case: Let $|E(G)|= 0$, then $v = 1$ and $f = 1$ (an isolated vertex). Then
$ 1 = 0 - 1 + 2 \Rightarrow 1 = 1$, therefore, claim holds for now

Let G have $|E(G)| = n, |V(G)| = v, |F(G)| = f$, and
assume that inequality $ f = n-v+2$ holds for this graph.

To prove: prove that claim holds for $|E(T)| = n+1$,

Let us have $G' = (V',E')$ such that $|E(G')| = n+1, |V(G')| = v, |F(G')| = f$, There are two kind of edges we can remove, cover both by case distinction:

**Case 1:** An edge that creates extra two faces, remove this edge $e\in E(G')$, then one of the faces are lost, so we have $f-1 = (n+1)-1-v+2 \Rightarrow f = n-v+2$, so we are at $IH$ again, now add $e$ back to $G'$, we get $f = n+1-v+2$, which was assumed by IH, so the claim must hold.

**Case 2:** An edge that creates no extra faces, remove this edge $e'\in E(G')$ , then no faces are lost, so we have $f=n-v+2$, which is the $IH$, now add $e'$ back to G', so we get $f = n+1-v+2$ number of faces is not influenced as e does not contribute to any extra faces in G, so inequality must still hold.

Since base case has been proved, all cases were covered and it has been proved for $n+1$ then, claim must hold

I feel like this proof has a lot of gaps, please help me find them so that I can improve.
Thank you

Comment: $f=n-v+2$ is an *equation*, not an *inequality*. More worrisome there seems to be no mention of *connected*. Euler only holds for connected graphs.

Comment: Oh yes sorry that is my bad, I confused it with a previous question that I did. "More worrisome there seems to be no mention of connected. Euler only holds for connected graphs.", hmm so when we delete an edge from a Tree for instance the euler formula does not hold then ?

Comment: Right. That decreases number of edges by one, but doesn't affect number of vertices or faces, so Euler goes bye-bye.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see, I believe that your proof is correct. As in the comments above, Euler's formula only holds for connected planar graphs.
I'm going to present a slightly more rigorous version here, but the same idea applies.

Define a **tree** to be an acyclic connected graph. It is known that if it has $v$ vertices then it will have exactly $v-1$ edges. One can prove this by induction and this is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1198263/proof-verification-prove-that-a-tree-with-n-vertices-has-n-1-edges).

We now proceed by induction, where a tree of $v$ vertices is our base case. Applying Euler's formula yields : $V-E + F= v - (v-1) + 1 = 2$ which holds.

Now take any planar connected graph with $v$ vertices that is not a tree. It must contain a cycle, so we remove an edge in the cycle. This decreases the number of faces and number of edges by 1, so the value of $V - E + F$ doesn't change. We keep removing edges until we reach a tree, and we are done.

Comment: I'm not sure how "clear" it is that a tree with $v$ vertices has $v-1$ edges. It's true, it's not super-hard to prove, but I don't think it's trivial, or obvious.

Comment: Gerry, on your advice I have retracted the word clear and included a link to the proof. I must apologize as I'm still getting used to the level of detail needed in these.